# How can add “Warm up” in unity 2d game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time, 2d

I want add "Warmup" to my game like Counter strike Warmup. I want a one-time 30s timer to "restart" the player to original position after 30s of game starting. How can I do this? I used the following code but it did not work.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TimerCountDown : MonoBehaviour
{
    float counter;
    Vector3 startPos;

    [SerializeField]
    Text textCounter;

    bool warmupOn;

    private void Start()
    {
        counter = 30;
        warmupOn = true;
        startPos = transform.position;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (warmupOn == true)
        {
            counter -= Time.deltaTime;
            textCounter.text = Mathf.Ceil(counter).ToString();
            Debug.Log("starting");

            if (counter == 0 || counter < 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("stoped");
                warmupOn = false;
                transform.position = startPos;               

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some details about what "not working" means?

Comment: Hi. Countdown Timer is working but player restart position not working.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `transform.position = startPos;` you only set the transform position of the transform that the script is sitting on. `transform` basically caches `GetComponent<Transform>`.

You need to get a reference to the player transform and then set that to startPosition.

The way you approach this isn't that good to begin with, you will want to separate this up into different scripts and have a system dedicated to managing player spawns, then hand over the task of resetting positions to the player spawn system from the countdown system.

Comment: And what tells you that this script is not maybe attached to the player object?

Comment: @derHugo if it was attached to the player gameobject it would reset the transform.position to startPos, given from his comment it seems like the Debug.Log was reached